# Compute memory required to allocated objects

Tags: java

I would like to compare memory usage, to allocate Calendar object and Joda's DateTime object.

```
// How much memory required to allocate 100 Calendar objects?
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    l = l + c.getTimeInMillis();
    CalendarList.add(c);
}

// How much memory required to allocate Joda TimeDate objects?
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
    l = l + dateTime.getMillis();
    DateTimeList.add(dateTime);
}
```

---

May I know is there any code I can add in to measure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use instrumentation to get an hint of memory usage:

```
public class MemUsage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instrumentation instr = InstrumentationAgent.getInstrumentation();
        if (instr == null) {
            System.err.println("No Instrumentation, use the VM option \"-javaagent:Instrumentation.jar\"");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("an implementation-specific approximation of the amount of storage");
        System.out.println("Calendar = " + instr.getObjectSize(Calendar.getInstance()));
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Other option: [MemoryMXBean](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.html) but I never used that.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Java visual vm](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/) tool, there you can see what objects take what memory. I don't think there is a "in code" solution that is correct in all cases with a few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at the following  [Java Specialists' newsletter](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue142.html)